# What is the difference between "wry" and "dry" humor?

Tags: meaning

Please describe the differences between *wry humor* and *dry humor*.

Research

- [This definition says *wry* literally means "twisted" and is associated with sarcasm](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wry).
- [This article suggests *dry* has to do with puns](http://www.ehow.com/how_2151193_develop-dry-sense-humor.html).

But I'm not really certain there actually *is* a difference. I think it's just as possible the two are completely interchangeable terms.

I'm looking for a canonical consensus of opinion (or a split opinion) here amongst the world's leading experts—yes, this means you, english.se.

Comment: Please describe what you've learned thus far through your research.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Wry" evolved from a meaning of "to twist".  Applied to humor, it refers to humor that is bitterly or disdainfully ironic or amusing; distorted or perverted in meaning;  warped, misdirected, or perverse; words that are unsuitable or wrong; scornful and mocking in a humorous way--it covers a lot of territory (see [WordReference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/wry)).  Here is a link to examples of wry humor: https://www.pinterest.com/karenegeberg/wry-humor/.  A few samples:

> Inside every older person is a younger person wondering what the hell happened.
>
> I'm sorry I hurt your feelings when I called you stupid.  I really thought you already knew.
>
> I swear; if my memory was any worse, I could plan my own surprise party.

"Dry" humor is often called deadpan humor because it is delivered with a straight face and a serious tone, as if it is not intended to be funny.  A good discussion of dry humor here: http://simplicable.com/new/dry-humor.

In general, humor is based on a sense of the unexpected, inexplicable, ridiculous and ironic.  The deadpan delivery enhances that because the serious tone makes it more-so, and may even lead to a "delayed reaction", where you don't recognize the humor until later.  Wry humor can be delivered in a deadpan manner.

A lot of comedy is delivered with facial expressions or acting out to provide a reinforcing image.  Some old-time comics would employ a technique like a drum "rimshot" to flag the punchline.  Some humor is just funny on a surface level, or incorporates words that sound funny.  What makes dry humor unique is that it isn't always obviously funny, especially with a deadpan delivery; you often need to think about it.  The humor is entirely within the meaning of the words.

Steven Wright's humor is a great example of dry humor.  Samples here: https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/s/steven_wright.html.  A few examples:

> I intend to live forever.  So far, so good.
>
> Whenever I think of the past, it brings back so many memories.
>
> I think it's wrong that only one company makes the game Monopoly.
>
> If it's a penny for your thoughts and you put in your two cents worth, then someone, somewhere is making a penny.
>
> What's another word for Thesaurus?
>
> I used to work in a fire hydrant factory.  You couldn't park anywhere near the place.

Comedian Henny Youngman was famous for one-liners delivered in a deadpan manner.  Much of his humor was both wry and dry.  For example, his most famous line:

> Take my wife ... please.

If you never saw the delivery, "Take my wife" was said as if he was using his wife as an example to set up a situation, as in "Take my wife [for example]."  After a brief pause, the "please" turned it into a request.

Comment: Adding another Steven Wright gem: "24 hour banking? I don't have time for that."