# What is a word that means contrary and funny

Tags: phrases, expressions, humor

I am trying to describe my sense of humor to be contrary and funny, a bit silly and irreverent (not choosing between 2 choices but making my own choice), and not disrespectfully so.  I thought about "snarky", but googling that it shows:

(of a person, words, or a mood) sharply critical; cutting; snide

These words feel negative and hurtful.  I want to find a word that is more humorous and light and happy, playful.

It doesn't have to be a word, a good phrase will work.

Thanks!

Comment: Would the British word "cheeky" fit your description?

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might have a ***[wry](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wry)*** sense of humor, which would generally be understood to mean ironic (or mildly sarcastic) or with a 'twist' (the root of *wry*). [Here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384686/what-is-the-difference-between-wry-and-dry-humor) an ELU response that addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're describing your sense of humor, "ironic" might fit.  I doesn't have any of the negative connotations that "snarky" has.